# How to set a radio button if we know the id of that button in android?

Tags: android

I want to set radio button with the Id of the button I have. How to do that?

Comment: want to set radio button? **"set" means??**

Comment: more explanation needed, put some effort on your question

Comment: Set means to check the radio button if I have the id of one of the button in radio gruop

Comment: please put your questions in a way someone can easily understand

Comment: In a radio group  have 5 radio buttons. I want to check the radio buttons based on the Button Id(Each radio button has its own ID).For example Id of one of the button is 11223344 how I can check that radio button

Comment: I found the answer for it. In a radio group if we have the id of one of the button we can use this piece of code to check it.

RadioGroup rgp;

int radioButtonId;

rgp.check(radioButtonId);

Answer (score 0):

```
 RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.1123344);
 rb1.setChecked(true);
```